# ES6 - How to get array item (function) of a specific context

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, publish-subscribe

Given a publish-subscribe pattern using ES6 as follows (extracted from https://davidwalsh.name/pubsub-javascript):

```
class PubSub {
    constructor() {
        this.handlers = [];
    }

    subscribe(event, handler, context) {
        if (typeof context === 'undefined') {
            context = handler;
        }
        {
            if (this.getHandler(event, handler) == null) {
                this.handlers.push({event: event, handler: handler.bind(context), key: Guid()});
            }
        }
    }

    unsubscribe(event, handler) {
        let filteredHandler = this.getHandler(event, handler);
        if (filteredHandler != null) {
            let idx = this.handlers.indexOf(filteredHandler);
            if (idx > -1) {
                this.handlers.splice(idx, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    publish(event, args) {
        this.handlers.forEach(topic => {
            if (topic.event === event) {
                topic.handler(args)
            }
        })
    }

    getHandler(event, handler) {
        if (this.handlers == null || this.handlers.length < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        let filtered = null;

        this.handlers.forEach(topic => {
            if (topic.event === event && topic.handler === handler) {
                filtered = topic;
            }
        });

        return filtered;
    }

    getNumOfSubsribers() {
        if (this.handlers != null && this.handlers.length > 0) {
            return this.handlers.length;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

The subscribe and publish methods work. However, the getHandler and unsubscribe method do not work as expected (getHandler seems returning null). I have tried to search around but could not get a satisfactory solution to this problem (not sure how a function bound to a given context can be filtered out from an array).

What have I done wrong in the code? Kindly advise me on getHandler and also unsubscribe part of the code.

Appreciate some kind help.

Comment: After you subscribe, what does "handlers" trace out to be? Is it empty or null? If it's empty, then something is either wrong with the subscription code, or you're feeding the subscription code something wrong. If handlers isn't null, then something is wrong with the get handlers code, or something went wrong with the original subscription preventing the code from finding the handler (e.g., if you are submitting a null event).

Comment: It turned out the handler returned was null. I was expecting to retrieve the correct handler that was bound to the correct context. With this result, I wanted to remove it from handlers list as dictated in unsubscribe method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is odd in a couple of ways.

The reason `getHandler` doesn't work is that the `handler` property of the object pushed on `handlers` is not the function that was passed in; it's the result of calling `bind` on that function. Formatted properly, this is `subscribe`:

```
subscribe(event, handler, context) {
    if (typeof context === 'undefined') {
        context = handler;
    }
    {
        if (this.getHandler(event, handler) == null) {
            this.handlers.push({
                event: event,
                handler: handler.bind(context),  // ** NOTE **
                key: Guid()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

That value will never be equal to the original, by definition.

Instead, it should include the original handler as well so it can check for it later. Let's also get rid of the pointless standalone block:

```
subscribe(event, handler, context) {
    if (typeof context === 'undefined') {
        context = handler;
    }
    if (this.getHandler(event, handler) == null) {
        this.handlers.push({
            event: event,
            handler: handler.bind(context),
            originalHandler: handler,        // ***
            key: Guid()
        });
    }
}
```

Now, `getHandler` can look for matches with `originalHandler`. While we're there, let's stop looping when we find the handler rather than keeping going, and use the semantically-appropriate `Array#find`:

```
getHandler(event, handler) {
    if (this.handlers == null || this.handlers.length < 1) {
        return null;
    }

    let filtered = this.handlers.find(topic => topic.event === event && topic.originalHandler === handler);
    return filtered;
}
```

---

There are other issues with the code (like binding the handler to itself if no `context` is provided), but a full code review is out of scope; the above is why `getHandler` doesn't work and thus why `unsubscribe` doesn't work. With that fix, `unsubscribe` should also work (though it seems odd to search twice).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Did a quick try on my code and it works. A quick question, the originalHandler in your example works for different contexts right? For eg, if i have serviceA.js and serviceB.js that both subscribe to the same event name and both have the same function names as handler bound to its respective context.

Comment: @oatcrunch: The *names* of the functions don't matter. `getHandler` works by looking for an entry with *that specific function*. (Remember, functions are objects, so `==` and `===` will only be true when you compare two arguments/variables that both refer to the same function.)